# Compiling multiple haml files into one html with gulp

Tags: html, gulp, haml

I've got gulp running compiling and minifying my scss and js files correctly, but for the life of my I can't seem to correctly compile haml files with the gulp-haml module.

The respective code in my gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
gulp.task('haml', function() {
 gulp.src('.app/**/*.haml')
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(haml())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./hamltest'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', [
  'styles', 
  'app',
  'haml'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch([
    './styles/',
    '.app/**/*.js',
    '.app/**/*.haml'
],
[
    'styles',
    'app',
    'haml'
 ]);
});

gulp.task('default', [
 'styles', 
 'scripts',
 'haml', 
 'watch'
]);
```

I've set up all my gulp variables and I'm running:

- gulp-haml -v 0.1.6
- haml -v 0.4.3
- gulp CLI -v 1.2.2
- Local -v 3.9.1

using the command: $ gulp in terminal to run everything

At this point I'm wondering if it's even possible to compile multiple haml files into one html or compile multiple haml files into a main haml file to then render into html.

Is using haml partials a better method to do this? Is this whole thing even possible with Gulp? Any insight would be much appreciated.

***Additional Info:*** I've also tried using the pipe order() and pipe concat() functions

Answer (score 0):

With gulp-haml Impossible to compile Ruby code like:

```
= Haml::Engine.new(File.read('./includes/menu-main.haml')).render
```

because gulp-haml has no full Ruby engine functionality. If you want to use Ruby, download it and install, then install haml for it (but Ruby requests are very slow ~1-3s). Or, use some other templater, like gulp-file-include, so you can compile then include your compiled .HTML files (im using gulp-jhaml, it has same features with gulp-haml):

```
var haml        = require('gulp-jhaml'),
    gih         = require('gulp-include-html'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('haml', function() {
  return gulp.src(['source-folder/*.haml'])
    .pipe(haml({}, {eval: false}))
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.error(err.stack) 
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source-folder/html'));
});
gulp.task('html-include', ['haml'], function () {  
  gulp.src(['source-folder/html/*.html'])
    .pipe(gih({
      prefix: '@@'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('result-folder'));
});
gulp.task('watch', ['html-include', 'browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('source-folder/*.haml', ['html-include']);
  gulp.watch('result-folder/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

You can also try [gulp-pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-pug) with a native function include. [Pug](https://pugjs.org) - was called 'Jade' before.